# Not able to fetch the data from database using JPQL query in springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpql

@Service
public class QuizService {

```
@Autowired
QuizDao quizDao;

@Autowired
QuestionDao questiondao;

public ResponseEntity<String> createQ( String category, int nOfQues, String title) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    List<Questions> questions= questiondao.findByCategoryANOfQuestions(category, nOfQues);
    
    Quiz quiz = new Quiz();
    
    quiz.setTitle(title);
    quiz.setQuestions(questions);
    
    
    quizDao.save(quiz);
    
    return new ResponseEntity<>("success", HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
}
```

@Repository
public interface QuestionDao extends JpaRepository<Questions,Integer> {

```
List<Questions> findByCategory(String category);
@Query(value= "select * from questions q Where q.category =: category ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT     :nOfQues" , nativeQuery= true)
List<Questions> findByCategoryANOfQuestions(String category, int nOfQues);
```

Not able to get questions in db. Using postgres . Please , this is first project and I am self learning. Any help would be appreciated.

Not showing any values in question table.

Comment: Can you add the code of Entities,QuizDao & QuestionDao?

Comment: Sure, @Repository
public interface QuestionDao extends JpaRepository<Questions,Integer> {

    List<Questions> findByCategory(String category);
    
    @Query(value= "select * from questions q Where q.category =:category ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT :nOfQues" , nativeQuery= true)
 List<Questions> findByCategoryANOfQuestions(String category, int nOfQues);

public interface QuizDao extends JpaRepository<Quiz,Integer> {

}

Comment: Please show a complete, runnable example which illustrates the problem. It's not clear whether you are calling `createQ`. Have you checked the DB contents directly via an SQL client?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of space you had given between : and param (=: category).

Comment: i tried , it still dint work.